# error at for loop: Expected an identifier in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting numbers from the list one by one to send SMS using `telephony` package, but inside my container, it is giving me an `error at for loop`.
Please let me know how can I avoid this error

My code is:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:epicare/Homepage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:telephony/telephony.dart';

class TriggeringAlert extends StatefulWidget {
  const TriggeringAlert({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  @override
  _TriggeringAlertState createState() => _TriggeringAlertState();
}

class _TriggeringAlertState extends State<TriggeringAlert> {
  // Get location
  Position _currentPosition;
  String _currentAddress;
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
  void initState(){
    startTimer();
    _getCurrentLocation();
    getCaregivers();
    super.initState();
  }
  Timer _timer;
  int _start = 10;
  void startTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    } else {
      _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(seconds: 1),
            (Timer timer) => setState(
              () {
            if (_start < 1) {
              timer.cancel();
            } else {
              _start = _start - 1;
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }


  }
  _getCurrentLocation() {
    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });
      _getAddressFromLatLng();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  _getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
      Placemark place = p[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress = "${place.locality}, ${place.country}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // Send SMS
  final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
  sendSMS(String number) {
    if (_currentPosition != null && _currentAddress != null)
      print('Address $_currentAddress');

    telephony.sendSms(
      to: number,
      message:
      "This is to inform you that Epilepsy attack is occurring right now\n My current Location is: $_currentAddress",
    );
    
  }
  User cuser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("User_data");
  List<String> numbers_list = List();
  //Caregivers
  void getCaregivers() {
    // Firebase
    fb
        .child(cuser.uid)
        .child("caregivers")
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.value;
      data.forEach((key, value) {
        setState(() {
          numbers_list.add(value['Caregiver_Number']);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffe8e5af),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
            child: Text(
              'TRIGGERING ALERT IN',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                fontSize: 21,
                color: const Color(0xff000000),
                height: 1.380952380952381,
              ),
              textHeightBehavior:
                  TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: size.width * 0.6,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 21),
            child: Text(
              'If it is a false alarm please cancel the alert ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 15,
                color: const Color(0xa8000000),
                height: 1.3333333333333333,
              ),
              textHeightBehavior:
                  TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              //color: Colors.white,
              height: size.height * 0.5,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              //padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
              child: Stack(
                alignment:AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    //color: Colors.yellow,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:35),
                    child: Text(
                      '$_start',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 50,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                        letterSpacing: 5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        height: 0.7,
                      ),
                      textHeightBehavior:
                      TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    //color: Colors.yellow,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:45),
                    child: Text(
                      'Seconds',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                        letterSpacing: 1.4000000000000001,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        height: 2.5,
                      ),
                      textHeightBehavior:
                      TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.scale(
                    scale: 5,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0x26a4a67f),
                        strokeWidth: 2.0,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 90,
          ),
          Container(
            //padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 85),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: _start==0
                ? numbers_list.length == 0
                ? Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "No caregivers")
                :(
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers_list.length; i++)
                {
                  sendSMS(numbers_list[i].toString());
                }
            )
                : ButtonTheme(
              height: 50.0,
              minWidth: 200.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28)),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Homepage(device: widget.device,);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Cancel Alert",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Errors at for loop:

```
error: Expected to find ')'
error: Expected an identifier
```

Comment: Can you share your "sendSMS" method?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing business logic and UI. Fluttertoast.showToast and sendSMS should be called in an event handler like a onPressed from a button. If _start=0, you need to return a widget, not call a function to run some logic

Comment: I think there is extra parenthesis after for loop braces above  ```: ButtonTheme```

Comment: @Gpack i don't want any UI in it, I just want to send SMS when Timer is finished, i.e when 10s timer is finished , SMs should be sent to the contacts I've added in firebase

Comment: So you want to build a screen which launch a timer of 10s and then sends the SMS, is that right? This means the user would have to stay for 10s on that screen, that's a long time. In any case, could you update your question with the code of the entire widget?

Comment: @Gpack Yes exactly, that's correct. The user has to wait for 10s to send SMS, in another case he could cancel before 10s are completed and in canceling it no SMS will be sent. 
Code updated in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:
Basically what I did was to move the code that sends the SMS to your `startTimer()` method and after 10s, the button "Cancel Alert" would disappear and is replaced by an empty SizedBox.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:epicare/Homepage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:telephony/telephony.dart';

class TriggeringAlert extends StatefulWidget {
  const TriggeringAlert({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  @override
  _TriggeringAlertState createState() => _TriggeringAlertState();
}

class _TriggeringAlertState extends State<TriggeringAlert> {
  // Get location
  Position _currentPosition;
  String _currentAddress;
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
  void initState(){
    startTimer();
    _getCurrentLocation();
    getCaregivers();
    super.initState();
  }
  Timer _timer;
  int _start = 10;
  void startTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    } else {
      _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(seconds: 1),
            (Timer timer) => setState(
              () {
            if (_start < 1) {
              timer.cancel();
              if (numbers_list.length == 0) Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "No caregivers");
              else {
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers_list.length; i++) {
                  sendSMS(numbers_list[i].toString());
                }
              }
            } else {
              _start = _start - 1;
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }


  }
  _getCurrentLocation() {
    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });
      _getAddressFromLatLng();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  _getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
      Placemark place = p[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress = "${place.locality}, ${place.country}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // Send SMS
  final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
  sendSMS(String number) {
    if (_currentPosition != null && _currentAddress != null)
      print('Address $_currentAddress');

    telephony.sendSms(
      to: number,
      message:
      "This is to inform you that Epilepsy attack is occurring right now\n My current Location is: $_currentAddress",
    );
    
  }
  User cuser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("User_data");
  List<String> numbers_list = List();
  //Caregivers
  void getCaregivers() {
    // Firebase
    fb
        .child(cuser.uid)
        .child("caregivers")
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.value;
      data.forEach((key, value) {
        setState(() {
          numbers_list.add(value['Caregiver_Number']);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffe8e5af),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
            child: Text(
              'TRIGGERING ALERT IN',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                fontSize: 21,
                color: const Color(0xff000000),
                height: 1.380952380952381,
              ),
              textHeightBehavior:
                  TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: size.width * 0.6,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 21),
            child: Text(
              'If it is a false alarm please cancel the alert ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 15,
                color: const Color(0xa8000000),
                height: 1.3333333333333333,
              ),
              textHeightBehavior:
                  TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              //color: Colors.white,
              height: size.height * 0.5,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              //padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
              child: Stack(
                alignment:AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    //color: Colors.yellow,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:35),
                    child: Text(
                      '$_start',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 50,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                        letterSpacing: 5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        height: 0.7,
                      ),
                      textHeightBehavior:
                      TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    //color: Colors.yellow,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:45),
                    child: Text(
                      'Seconds',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                        letterSpacing: 1.4000000000000001,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        height: 2.5,
                      ),
                      textHeightBehavior:
                      TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.scale(
                    scale: 5,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0x26a4a67f),
                        strokeWidth: 2.0,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 90,
          ),
          Container(
            //padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 85),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: _start == 0
                ? SizedBox.shrink()
                : ButtonTheme(
              height: 50.0,
              minWidth: 200.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28)),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Homepage(device: widget.device,);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Cancel Alert",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```